# Tomcat7 detect Memory Leak

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, memory-leaks, vaadin

I have made a simple application using vaadin 6 witch contains a callendar and people can make some appointments in there.

The problem is, when more then like 10 people connects, the  memory usage is 95%.(I have 125mb on server, running Ubuntu Server 32 bit).

Here are the screenshots:[image]

If I enter tomcat and test if fomr memory leaks i get:

> The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed), but their
> classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus causing a memory
> leak (use a profiler to confirm):
> /myapp
> /myapp
> /myapp
> /myapp
> /myapp

When I installed tomcat I just made a clean install, and changed the ports so i can connect to it on port 80, also I have added some users so I can connect to web manager. THat is all

Can there be something in my code or I did not set up tomcat correctly that causes this memory leak?

Comment: 125MB of RAM? For an application server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your getting this because static variables. When you are restart your server or application the static variables will not unload some time. This link will help you to understand about this:http://frankkieviet.blogspot.ca/2006/10/classloader-leaks-dreaded-permgen-space.html

Comment: I am using a private static final object in my application.From what I have read there, this is what cases the problem. I don't know how to free up the memory after the app closes. Can you give me a fix for this?

Comment: You can get fix from above link. Try to avoid restart your app in server or redeploy your app.